# How should I create a list of firewall table in my Windows Server to show if port 443 is blocked?

Tags: powershell

I would like to list out all rules that block port 80 for inbound traffic in my windows firewall. Below is the Powershell command I found, but I can't make it work. Am I missing something?

```
Get-NetFirewallRule |
Format-Table -Property Name,
DisplayName,
DisplayGroup,
@{Name='Protocol';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).Protocol}},
@{Name='LocalPort';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Where-Object -Property LocalPort -EQ 80).LocalPort}},
@{Name='RemotePort';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).RemotePort}},
@{Name='RemoteAddress';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter).RemoteAddress}},
Enabled,
Profile,
Direction,
Action
```

Output:

[image: Result]

Comment: Please be more specific than "can't make it work" - what happens, and how does it deviate from what you expected?

Comment: Hi Mathias, Please have a look at the output is attached. This is all the firewall rules and I would like to list out only port 80 LocalPort that are Block. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would start like this.  It's faster to lead with get-netfirewallportfilter.  Is it port 443 or 80?  Localport could be an array where one element is 443.

```
Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | where localport -eq 443 | Get-NetFirewallRule | 
  where action -eq block
```